# Why does $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt u}du \neq \ln(\sqrt u)$ hold true?

Tags: integration

I do know the integral of the function written in the title. My question is a different one. I do not understand why this holds true : $\int \limits_{}^{}\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{u}}{du}\neq\ln(\sqrt{u})$. As far as I understand the derivative of $\ln({x})$ is $\frac{1}{x}$. I also know that $\int \limits_{}^{}\frac{1}{x}{du} = \ln(|x|)$ holds true.

What am I not seeing? Where do I think wrong?

Comment: I would suggest you review the Chain rule for differentiation.

Comment: When you differentiate $\ln(\sqrt{u})$ and expect the original answer back, what happens?

Comment: Also note that $\ln(u^{1/2}) = \frac{1}{2} \ln u$, $u > 0$ of course.

Comment: @DavidMitra I now see it. Thanks

Comment: @TobyMak Thanks for your comments, I see now where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be thinking is that $$\int\frac1{f(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\ln[|f(x)|],$$ leaving constants aside for a second. However, your intuition is not quite correct. Notice that $$[\ln(f)]'(x)=\frac1{f(x)}f'(x),$$ due to the chain rule of derivatives. So in actuality $$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\ln[|f(x)|],$$ leaving constants aside.

Instead, what you have here is $$\int\frac1{\sqrt{u}}\,\mathrm{d}u=\int{u^{-\frac12}}\,\mathrm{d}u,$$ and here, you can use the power rule.